# Android Protected variable storage even after factory reset

Tags: android

I'm working on Aosp. I want to keep a variable in the system but   When I use a shared preference, the variable is deleted when I perform a Factory reset. I need to change and save the variable I want to keep. Think like a Mac address

Comment: "I need to change and save the variable I want to keep. Think like a Mac address" - mac addresses do not change, so not really a good example.  Please provide context - "I'm working on Aosp" would infer you're not restricted to normal application layer constraints like those in `SharedPreferences`, but If you're writing an application then stating Aosp doesn't make much sense

Comment: Yes I can change set/get Mac addresses from Native layer

Comment: Maybe we need to access boot environment variables but i don't know how can I do

Comment: My app is an system  app in Android but the device is not rooted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all the variables you want to save into a json and save it in internal storage
and you can retrive it whenever you  want

example code for read and write

```
private void saveConfig(String data) {
try {
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("config.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
    outputStreamWriter.write(data);
    outputStreamWriter.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
}   }

private String readConfig() {

String data = "";

try {
    InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput("config.txt");

    if ( inputStream != null ) {
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String receiveString = "";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
            stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        data = stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("Error", "File not found: " + e.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Error", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
}
return data;
}
```

and your json can be

```
{
  "variable1": "Value",
  "variable2": false
}
```

Comment: So where would this get written to that would survive a factory reset, which is probably the most important part?

Comment: device's internal storage

Comment: But external storage can be deleted after Factory reset

Comment: Also I am  working on Aosp maybe have another solution

Comment: i solved problem , i created a file in tmp/ and write read it